# Printer (Kyocera P602cdn) randomly prints out postscript code

Tags: printer, linux-mint, cups, laser-printer, postscript

I am using a Kyocera P602cdn printer (latest drivers from their website) with CUPS (1.7.2) on Linux Mint (kernel 3.13.0-48).

In around 50% of my print jobs not the document comes out but postscript code like the following:

```
agelevel } { 1 } ifelse
                       2 lt { /Helvetica findfont 12 scalefont 50 500
```

This behavior is non-deterministic, the same document will print out fine first and fail to print right after or the other way around, the type of input does not seem to matter.

Answer (score 0):

By what you're saying, I assume you are using a PostScript driver. I know Kyocera have a generic PCL driver that can be used, available for all platforms. May I suggest that you try using the PCL driver rather than the PostScript one, and see if a similar problem occurs. At a photocopier and printer company I provide the IT services for, they always suggest PCL when providing remote support, hence why I suggest it here.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to force the printer into PostScript from its front panel or web interface. That way the printer will always interpret the PS code correctly.

On the assumption the printer is a P6021CDN instead of P602CDN, the [Operation Guide](http://cdn.kyostatics.net/dlc/be/documentation/usermanual/p6021cdn_p6026cdn8.-downloadcenteritem-Single-File.downloadcenteritem.tmp/ECOSYS%20P6021cdn_P6026cdn_OG_Rev.01_(ENG).pdf) shows how to select KPDL (Kyocera's PS emulation) on page 4-41 (pg 109 of the PDF). Start by pressing Menu (pg 74). Press the down arrow to get to Print Settings (pg 105). Then press the right arrow once, and the down arrow until you get to Emulation. Press OK and then the down arrow until you get to KPDL. Then press OK and Menu to exit.

The default is "KPDL Auto" which tells the printer to auto-switch languages. I'm guessing it is making the wrong choice, so PS is printed as text instead.